# Magento 2 Get Customer's Telephone after registration

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am new to Magento2 and I was wondering if someone could help me echo out Customer's Address information in an activation email to Admin.  Below is the code I am using to build the Customer's information.

```
->setTemplateVars(
            [
                'email' => $customer->getEmail(),
                'firstname' => $customer->getFirstname(),
                'lastname' => $customer->getLastname(),
                'company' => $customer->getAddress()->getCompany(), //DOESN'T WORK!!
                'telephone' => $customer->getAddress()->getTelephone(), //DOESN'T WORK!!
                'taxvat' => $customer->getTaxvat(),
                'website' => $customer->getCustomAttribute('website')->getValue(),
            ]
        );
```

Email, Firstname, Lastname, TaxVat and Custom Attribute "Website" are all working and showing properly on my email.  However, I can't get the information for Company Name, Telephone, Address, etc.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Can you dump this   $customer->getAddress(); and see what data you are getting in this.

Answer (score 0):

To get customer phone number and company info you need to used this things.

```
$customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getTelephone(); // For Telephone

$customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getCompany(); // For Company
```